# How to find the highest numbered version of text?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to find the highest numbered version of text? For example I have the data with text+digit:
Supra1, Supra2,...,SupraN in column1: translated_description.

```
select
    *
from
    oe.product_descriptions
where
    translated_description like '%Supra%';
```

I need to extract the value from another column (column2) for the highest number e.g. N=30 for Supra30 in column1.

Comment: Looks like a bad data model to me. If you must know that the product is Supra and you must know the version number, why then is there not a column for the product name and another for the version in your table? I suggest you fix your data model rather than circumventing its issues in every other query.

Comment: Your request would have greatly benefited from sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

If all of the values in `column1` have numbers with the same number of digits, you can order by it and use the `fetch first` syntax:

```sql
SELECT   column2
FROM     mytable
WHERE    column1 LIKE 'Supra%'
ORDER BY column1 DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

If the number of digits in `column1` varies, you'll have to extract them, convert the number, and sort numerically:

```sql
SELECT   column2
FROM     mytable
WHERE    column1 LIKE 'Supra%'
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(column1, 'Supra', '')) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Comment: the column1 contains descriptions (e.g. word word word Supra2 word word or  e.g.2 word Supra15 word word etc.). I need to extract the highest number of Supra and add the value from column2 for this specific Supra.

Comment: @katarzynat then the sample dataset within the question will be expected to be more clearly described.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `regexp_substr` to extract the number and then apply max on it:

```
SELECT max(to_number(regexp_substr(t.translated_description, 'Supra([0-9]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)))
FROM oe.product_descriptions t
```

This will extract the number, assuming that the format of the content of the column is `SOMETEXTnumber`

Comment: I've tried and it shows me number 3 but in reality the highest digit for Supra is 9 :(

Comment: Is there more than 1 number in each column?

Comment: Yes, it is more than 1 number in each column

Comment: something like this: 10GB Removable hard disk drive for 10GB Removable HD drive. Supra7 disk drives provide the latest technology to improve enterprise performance, increasing the maximum data transfer rate up to 160MB/s.

Comment: @katarzynat This should be in the question.. Try the code now.

Answer (score 0):

If there could be more than 1 Supra in the column and if the numbers after the word supra could be 1 or 2 then (just for testing) you could have data like this:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 1 "ID", '10GB Removable HDD ... Supra7 disk drives ... transfer rate up to 160MB/s' "COL_1" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", 'Some words ... Supra9 some more words ... and numbers 16 - 32GB' "COL_1" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ID", 'Words, words, ... Supra12, and Supra13 are considered better than Supra15... words, words' "COL_1" From Dual 
        ),
```

In this case you should check where the Supra words are located within the string and get ridd of everyting infront. So, here is a cte checking for three words Supra within the text:

```sql
    supras AS
        (
            Select 
              ID,
              CASE WHEN InStr(Upper(COL_1), 'SUPRA', 1, 1) > 0 THEN SubStr(COL_1, InStr(Upper(COL_1), 'SUPRA', 1, 1)) END "SUPRA_1",
              CASE WHEN InStr(Upper(COL_1), 'SUPRA', 1, 2) > 0 THEN SubStr(COL_1, InStr(Upper(COL_1), 'SUPRA', 1, 2)) END "SUPRA_2",
              CASE WHEN InStr(Upper(COL_1), 'SUPRA', 1, 3) > 0 THEN SubStr(COL_1, InStr(Upper(COL_1), 'SUPRA', 1, 3)) END "SUPRA_3"
            From
              tbl
        )

        ID SUPRA_1                                                                                   SUPRA_2                                                       SUPRA_3                   
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------
         1 Supra7 disk drives ... transfer rate up to 160MB/s                                                                                                                                
         2 Supra9 some more words ... and numbers 16 - 32GB                                                                                                                                  
         3 Supra12, and Supra13 are considered better than Supra15... words, words                   Supra13 are considered better than Supra15... words, words    Supra15... words, words
```

And, finaly, this resulting dataset could be transformed to just numbers among which you should select the MAX one:

```sql
-- Main SQL
SELECT    MAX(GREATEST(SUPRA_1, SUPRA_2, SUPRA_3)) "MAX_SUPRA"
FROM      
    (
        Select 
            ID,
            CASE  WHEN INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(SUPRA_1, 6, 1)) > 0 And INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(SUPRA_1, 7, 1)) > 0 THEN To_Number(SubStr(SUPRA_1, 6, 2)) 
                  WHEN INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(SUPRA_1, 6, 1)) > 0 THEN To_Number(SubStr(SUPRA_1, 6, 1))
            ELSE 0
            END "SUPRA_1",
            --
            CASE  WHEN INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(SUPRA_2, 6, 1)) > 0 And INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(SUPRA_2, 7, 1)) > 0 THEN To_Number(SubStr(SUPRA_2, 6, 2)) 
                  WHEN INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(SUPRA_2, 6, 1)) > 0 THEN To_Number(SubStr(SUPRA_2, 6, 1))
            ELSE 0
            END "SUPRA_2",
            --
            CASE  WHEN INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(SUPRA_3, 6, 1)) > 0 And INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(SUPRA_3, 7, 1)) > 0 THEN To_Number(SubStr(SUPRA_3, 6, 2)) 
                  WHEN INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(SUPRA_3, 6, 1)) > 0 THEN To_Number(SubStr(SUPRA_3, 6, 1))
            ELSE 0
            END "SUPRA_3"
        From
            supras
    )


 MAX_SUPRA
----------
        15

-- Below is result of the inner query in main sql
        ID    SUPRA_1    SUPRA_2    SUPRA_3
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          7          0          0 
         2          9          0          0 
         3         12         13         15
```

Answer (score -2):

if you use SQL SERVER ,you can try this Query:

```
select ID as Column1,CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ID,6, (LEN(ID)-5))) as Column2 
from T
order by  CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ID,6, (LEN(ID)-5))) desc
```

Comment: According to **Oracle** tag, katarzynat is NOT using SQL Server.

Comment: @Littlefoot  Sorry, because of the sql tag, I wasn't sure if they were using sql server or not, that's why I said at first, if you use SQL SERVER ,you can try this Query

Comment: SQL is tag for a *language*; there are tags related to databases themselves, such as Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, ... Sometimes it is unclear what people actually want (when database tag is missing, or when they attach tags for several different databases). Though, in this case, it is pretty much clear - it *is* Oracle.

Comment: @Littlefoot Thank you for your help, I did not know that sql is tag for a language, I thought it is also used for sql server

Comment: You're welcome. Nope, SQL isn't equal to MS SQL Server :) There are various tags related to that database, e.g. "sql-erver", "sql-server-2008", "sql-server-2005", "sql-server-2012" etc.